# Exception in thread "main" java.lang.ClassCastException: WordCount cannot be cast to org.apache.hadoop.util.Tool

Tags: hadoop

I'm trying to execute new api mapreduce wordcount example. This is my program and I'm using hadoop-core-1.0.4.jar as plugin.

```
import java.io.IOException;
import java.util.Iterator;

import org.apache.hadoop.conf.Configuration;
import org.apache.hadoop.fs.Path;
import org.apache.hadoop.io.IntWritable;
import org.apache.hadoop.io.LongWritable;
import org.apache.hadoop.io.Text;
import org.apache.hadoop.mapreduce.Job;
import org.apache.hadoop.mapreduce.Mapper;
import org.apache.hadoop.mapreduce.Reducer;
import org.apache.hadoop.mapreduce.lib.input.FileInputFormat;
import org.apache.hadoop.mapreduce.lib.output.FileOutputFormat;
import org.apache.hadoop.util.Tool;
import org.apache.hadoop.util.ToolRunner;




public class NewWordCount {

    public static class WordMapper extends Mapper<LongWritable, Text, Text, IntWritable> {

        @Override
        protected void map(LongWritable key, Text value, Context context)
                throws IOException, InterruptedException {
            String line = value.toString();
            String[] words = line.split("\\W+");
            for (String word : words) {
                context.write(new Text(word), new IntWritable(1));
            }
        }

    }

    public static class WordReducer extends Reducer<Text, IntWritable, Text, IntWritable> {

        protected void reduce(Text key,  Iterator<IntWritable> values,
                Context context)
                throws IOException, InterruptedException {

            /*int sum = 0;
            for (IntWritable value:values) {
                sum += value.get();
            }*/
            int sum = 0;
            while (values.hasNext()) {
                sum += values.next().get();
            }

            context.write(key, new IntWritable(sum));

        }

    }



        public static void main(String[] args) throws Exception
        {
            Configuration conf = new Configuration();
            int exitCode=ToolRunner.run((Tool) new NewWordCount(), args);

            System.exit(exitCode);
        }
        public int run(String[] args) throws IOException, InterruptedException, ClassNotFoundException
        {

            Path inputPath=new Path(args[0]);
            Path outputPath=new Path(args[1]);
            Configuration conf = new Configuration();
            Job job = new Job(conf,"word count");
            job.setJarByClass(NewWordCount.class);
            job.setMapperClass(WordMapper.class);
            job.setReducerClass(WordReducer.class);
            job.setOutputKeyClass(Text.class);
            job.setOutputValueClass(IntWritable.class);

            FileInputFormat.setInputPaths(job,inputPath);
              FileOutputFormat.setOutputPath(job,outputPath);
            job.setNumReduceTasks(2);
        //  job.setPartitionerClass(VCPartitioner.class);
            job.waitForCompletion(true);
            //job.submit();
            return 0;
        }

    }
```

While exceuting I'm getting the following error:

```
Exception in thread "main" java.lang.ClassCastException: NewWordCount cannot be cast to org.apache.hadoop.util.Tool
        at NewWordCount.main(NewWordCount.java:59)
        at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
        at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:39)
        at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:25)
        at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:597)
        at org.apache.hadoop.util.RunJar.main(RunJar.java:208)
```

Can someone please tell how to resolve this error? Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can't cast `NewWordCount` since it is not implementing `Tool` interface.

Remove this line:

```
int exitCode=ToolRunner.run((Tool) new NewWordCount(), args);
```

You can simply have the `main` method (after copying the contents of run method to main).

And to run it:

```
hadoop NewWordCount input output
```

Comment: I tried your code. But still I'm getting  cannot be cast to org.apache.hadoop.util.Tool error.Casting to Tool i'm doing this line in main method:  int exitCode=ToolRunner.run((Tool) new NewWordCount(), args);